# accessing a list of integer associated with a command line parameter

Tags: c++, gflags

I'm using gflags in c++ for parsing of command line parameters. I would like to have a command line flag that accepts a list of parameters. For example `param` in the example below.

```
./myprog --param 0 1 2 3
```

How can I access a list of integers associated with this parameter?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using C++ (edited question)

Comment: Probably should add a C++ tag as well to get more notice.

Comment: So in `--param 0 1 2 3`, where the flags end and positional parameters start?

Comment: a good question. But in my case I am not using any.

Comment: `gflags` doesn't know you are not using positional parameters. I suggest you use something like `--param 0,1,2,3` or `--param "0 1 2 3"`, either one is standard and won't confuse the hell out of users. `--param 0 1 2 3` is non-standard and confusing, please don't use this syntax even if your flags engine can support it.

Comment: I completely agree. your suggestion of using commas for separating the parameters seems best. But does gflags support it? I haven't found how to do it, except defining this parameter as string and parse it myself

Comment: gflags doesn't support any complex syntax such as comma-separated lists. It gives you a string and you parse it with your own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gflags not supported array output, its just skipping unknown data, so you can choose: 
Choice 1, parse args manually before gFlags,but add param to gflags - for no error parsing, for example:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <gflags/gflags.h>

   DEFINE_string(param, "string", "string"); 

   int main (int argc, char **argv) 
   {
        vector<int> param;
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) 
        {
            if (!strcmp(argv[i], "--param")) 
            {
                for (++i; i < argc; i++) 
                {
                    if (!isdigit(argv[i][0]))
                        break;
                    param.push_back(atoi(argv[i]));
                }
            }
        }
        gflags::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, false); 
        return 0;
    }
```

Choice 2:
Modify your input command line for example to : --param 0,1,2,3
and receive param as string in gFlags, split string by ',' and convert to array of integer.

Comment: I think choice 2 is better. I'll try that.