# Is there a way to pass an array of ints with a command line parameter in GFlags?

Tags: c++, gflags

I want to pass an array of ints in the following way:

`./main --scores 1 49 1 24 4 5 6`

I did find a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125887/accessing-a-list-of-integer-associated-with-a-command-line-parameter) but it's sort of old, hopefully it's changed now. The accepted answer says I should pass them as string with a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. GFlags doesn't support complex command-line syntax, just simple flags with primitive-typed parameters. You *could* pass them as a delimited string, but if you really want to go all fancy with your command line usage, you'd probably be better served with a library designed for that, like GNU getopt.